# How does Zac's passive trigger on-kill effects?

Tags: league-of-legends

[Zac's](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Zac) passive splits him into four globules when he would die, which crawl back to his death point and reform if they survive. These are targetable by attacks and abilities, and if all four die before reforming, Zac is killed.

Cho'Gath, Nasus, Sion, and Veigar all have abilites that have an additional effect if they kill an entity. For Nasus, Sion, and Veigar; this effect is doubled if the entity was a major entity.

My question then, is this. Do Zac's globules count as an entity for the purpose of this ability? If so, are they major or minor entities?

Comment: It isn't counted as major thing regarding killstreaks! I've seen someone not being able to penta because it took to long to kill Zac and then another four Zacies. The counter didn't get reset after killing Zac himself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, "Zacies" are worth the same as **pets** (Elise's spiders, Malzahar's voidlings, etc.) They **WILL** give you a bonus if killed by Cho's R, Nasus's Q, etc, but it will **NOT** count as a champ kill. I was wondering the same thing and tested it out with some friends in a custom. Then again that was 4 days following his release.

EDIT: As to clarify the answer, just like for Kog'Maw and Yorick, the killing blow against Zac is the last hit that turns him into the 4 "Zacies", not the last hit against the last "Zacie". This is **the only hit** that counts as a champion kill against him.

EDIT 2 : I'm getting out of the boundaries of this question to adress some of your doubts. In LoL, a **kill** has several **definitions**. First of all, the one that counts in the kill score, for killstreaks, etc. : It is the one that turns the player's screen black-and-white, to be as precise as possible. In the case of all passives that give you "a last chance", such as Anivia's and Zac's, it is last hit that "forbids" the player to come back (killing the egg, the last "Zacie"..). Then again, as to the last hits that trigger abilities, it is another definition that usually comes into play. It's the **"entity"** last hit. Every "living" structure in LoL has an **entity type**. For, creeps it's "creep", for champions it's "champion" (and this counts as the "champion-kill" for abilities), for pets it's "pet-controllable" or "pet-IA" (names may not be exact), and this is the case for Yorick's ghost, Elise's spiders, Malzahar's voidlings, etc. AND Zac's "Zacies". Using an ability that scales on kills checks the **entity type**. And in the case of Zac, retrieves a "champion" type. It then awards the player the champion kill bonus. Hope this clarified everything for you.

Comment: I'm curious as to whether or not killing the last zacie with the ability would count as a major since it would be the killing blow for zac as well.

Comment: No, the ability bonus will be activated if casted as the "killing blow" on Zac, even if the 4 "Zacies" are spawned right after.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mentioned Anivia without thinking it through. Correcting it now.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the credit for the kill and thus what the skill should be based off of is given by killing the last zacie, not who does that damage that activates his passive. I killed the last zacie after my teammates "killed" him and activated his passive, and I was the player that received the credit for the kill.

Comment: Also the kog'maw and yorick edit you added has nothing to do with zac, the passives are not even similar as kog's just let's him run around and then explode(he's dead no matter what) and yoricks only brings him back for a short period(he still dies no matter what, even if noone attacks his "ghost") so the only character that zac's passive can be compared to is anivia's. And anivia's kill is rewarded to whoever kills the egg, not whoever puts her into egg.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't online this weekend. So, as to answer your doubts :

The game mechanics of LoL are somewhat obscure around the corners. I'm going to do a last edit in minutes to clarify everything.

Comment: To add some handy info: I've also had a killing blow on Zac, without actually hitting him by killing one of his blobs (he tower dived me, and died to the tower as I ran, I did 0 damage to him, tower finished him off, all I did was kill a blob to get credit).