# Damage to Minions works on Zac's Blobs?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've heard that you can smite Zac's Blobs as if they were minions.
So if that is true, does it mean that lantern passive effect can also proc on them? 
And what about the extra damage to minions mastery?
In general are there any special rules for them or do they just count as minions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've yet to check the details for these items and masteries (if it only mentions neutral monsters and minions, then it won't proc on "Zacies") but you should know that **Smite** has always been fully functional on **PETS**. You can refer to my answer on [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/113699/how-does-zacs-passive-trigger-on-kill-effects/) to fully grasp why Zac's blobs count as pets.

TL:DR; Zac's blobs are not minions, they are pet entities and can then be smited. If any items or mastery mentions that it procs on neutral monsters and minions only, then it won't have **any effect** on pets, and so on Zac's blobs. Smite clearly states (or stated ?) that it works on minions, neutral monsters, and pets (such as Malz's voidlings, Annie's Tibbers, etc).

Comment: The detail that smite ALSO works on pets could be the key here. Thx for this. I'll wait a bit just to confirm that in fact those masteries and items don't work on zac's passive. but my hunch also tells me they won't. It would weaken his passive a lot after all...

Comment: Makes me wonder if you can smite Anivia's Egg, haha..

Comment: @Joetjah No, Anivia's Egg has a "champion" entity parameter, which makes it untargetable with smite =)

Comment: @Joetjah Haha I don't think it's a pet. Just a form. But it would be funny.
They should make an Easter Bird Anivia (Runescape Reference) that would turn into an Easter Egg (would go well with Easter Bunny Teemo) XD

Comment: Definitely a no go on the anivia egg smite. She is my main and that would break her as a champion. A nice little piece of info to know about zac is that his passive works the same as anivia's when in turret range. If anivia gets egged while taking shots from a turret and is still in range after being egged, the turret will continue shooting her in egg form. This applies equally to zac and the turret will continue attacking the zacies until they are all gone.

Comment: and what if 1 Zacies is out of turret's range and then crawl in range ?

Comment: It attacks whichever ones are in range first. So by the time the other three are dead, the fourth would be close enough for it to hit. It also might have an extended range for the shots on zac. That part would need to be tested though.

Comment: It doesnt have an extended range in any special case, of that I'm sure.